# pass arraylist via android activity

Tags: android, arraylist

> ```
>         System.out.println("here ");
>         Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
>         System.out.println("here2 ");
>         ArrayList<Question> ques = extras.getParcelableArrayList("authoritems");
>         System.out.println("here "+ques.size());
>
>
>             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
>                     ListNameActivity.class);
>             System.out.println("accounitems "+accountItems.size());
>             Bundle b = new Bundle();
>             b.putParcelableArrayList("authoritems", accountItems);
>             i.putExtras(b);
>             startActivity(i);
>             overridePendingTransition(R.anim.dux_qact_fade_in,
>                     R.anim.dux_qact_fade_out);
>             finish();
> ```

I get printed accounitems 35
then i get printed here
then printed here 2
but it crashes on `ArrayList<Question> ques = extras.getParcelableArrayList("authoritems");`
why is that? and what am i doing wrong?

The class question is below

> ```
>   import android.os.Parcel;
>    import android.os.Parcelable;
>    public class Question implements Parcelable {
> public String getTitle() {
>     return title;
> }
> public void setTitle(String title) {
>     this.title = title;
> }
> ```

```
public String getSubTitle() {
    return subTitle;
}

public void setSubTitle(String subTitle) {
    this.subTitle = subTitle;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public String getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

String title="";
String subTitle="";
String id="";
String url="";
String latitude="";
String longitude="";

public Question(String title, String subTitle, String id, String url, String latitude, String longitude) {
    this.title = title;
    this.subTitle = subTitle;
    this.id = id;
    this.url = url;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

// Your existing methods go here. (There is no need for me to re-write them.) 

// The following methods that are required for using Parcelable
private Question(Parcel in) {
    // This order must match the order in writeToParcel()
    title = in.readString();
    subTitle = in.readString();
    id = in.readString();
    url = in.readString();
    latitude = in.readString();
    longitude = in.readString();
    // Continue doing this for the rest of your member data
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    // Again this order must match the Question(Parcel) constructor
    out.writeString(title);
    out.writeString(subTitle);
    out.writeString(id);
    out.writeString(url);
    out.writeString(latitude);
    out.writeString(longitude);
    // Again continue doing this for the rest of your member data
}

// Just cut and paste this for now
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

}
```

Comment: Could we see the logcat?

Comment: i show it for u . it gets printed accountitems 35, then gets printed hee..then gets printed here 2.. but  after this  ArrayList<Question> ques = extras.getParcelableArrayList("authoritems");
        System.out.println("here "+ques.size()); it goesnt get printed. it crashes on getparcelablearraylist

Comment: ok, but it crash with what error?

Comment: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called  CREATOR on class com.netvariant.zain.model.Question
that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are getting the error `Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class com.netvariant.zain.model.Question` you need to implement a creator in your `Question` class, something like this:

```
  public static final Parcelable.Creator<Question> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Question>() {
     public Question createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
           ///
        }

       public Question[] newArray(int size) {
          ///
      }
   };
```